# Anyone knows about Bhabisya Malika?

Tags: india

Are the predictions of Bhavishya Malika true? If you know, tell me whether it is fake or real. I have researched it for over 6 months and observed something scary! I want to share my research.

Comment: I guess, you are talking about Bhavishya malika Purana. I heard that it makes some predictions. I never read it. If you have a link of the book, please share.

Comment: I removed the opinion part. Because according to this site's rule, if you ask for opinions, your question will get closed.